# Android Studio. Spinner control not in the Palette. Normal?

Tags: android, android-studio

Installed Android Studio 14.    Why is the Spinner control not in the Palette?   Are you supposed to code it by hand in the XML?   I've seen both methods in Youtube videos.

Also, where is the best place to ask these simple kind of quick questions when Google/YT is a dead end?  Is there a Slack channel, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use android studio **4.0.1**, and the spinner is in palette:

[image]